# Write a python program to input an integer n and print sum of all its even and odd digits separately

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Digits mean numbers not places

I tried but the logic is wrong I know

```
N=input()
L=len(N)
N=int(N)
sum_e=0
sum_o=0
for i in range(0,L+1):
    if i%2==0:
        sum_e=sum_e+i
    else:
        sum_o=sum_o+i
print(sum_e, sum_o)
```

Comment: maybe don't use single letter variables

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this more succinctly by modulating the input value as follows:

```
N = abs(int(input('Enter a number: ')))

eo = [0, 0]

while N != 0:
    v = N % 10
    eo[v & 1] += v
    N //= 10

print(*eo)
```

**Sample:**

```
Enter a number: 1234567
12 16
```

Comment: This is not exactly what OP requested, I didn't want to modify your answer as is was a substantial change (+1 for the nice approach though, I provided a modified version in my answer)

Comment: @mozway I really need to read the questions properly. You're absolutely right - this is not what was asked for. Code edited. btw - I tend to avoid divmod because it's slow

Answer (score 0):

```
N=input()

sum_e=0
sum_o=0

for i in N:
    if int(i)%2==0:
        sum_e += int(i)
    else:
        sum_o += int(i)

print(sum_e, sum_o)
```

Let it remain string so we can iterate the digits and later convert it to Integer

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary:

```
N = input()
# N = '1234567'

out = {}
for c in N:
    c = int(c)
    key = 'odd' if c%2 else 'even'
    out[key] = out.get(key, 0) + c

print(out['even'], out['odd'])
# 12 16
```

Or with a method similar to @Cobra's:

```
N = int(input())
# N = 1234567

out = [0, 0]

while N>0:
    N, n = divmod(N, 10)
    out[n%2] += n

print(*out)
# 12 16
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
num = int(input())

evenSum = 0 
oddSum = 0

while num > 0 :
    last = num % 10
    
    if last % 2 == 0 :
        evenSum += last
    else :
        oddSum += last
        
    num = num // 10
    
print(evenSum, " ", oddSum)
```